# Filter options and display results using JOIN from separate table

Tags: mysql, join

Got a problem here I almost have down but missing a small piece I think.  I am taking user info such as width,height,material(s),type, and min. bid/max. bid..I want to use those parameters against a large database I constructed to show only the results that land between the user parameters.  As of now I have a query such as:

```
"SELECT 
bp.*, b.company 
FROM `DBPREFIXwindows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `DBPREFIXwindows_brands` b ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
WHERE 
bp.width = '24'
AND bp.height = '30'
AND bp.material = 'Vinyl' # This is if you use 1 for vinyl
AND bp.type = 'Casement' OR 'Vinyl'
AND (bp.cost >= '500' AND bp.cost <= '1000' )"
```

This is great if I want to query only static results; however, I have a table called `Windows_last_submission` that holds information such as width/height/material(s)/etc.. to use againsts the database `DBPREFIXwindows_brands` / `DBPREFIXwindows_brands_products`.

Basically how will I substitute, for example, the '24' in 'width' with the information in `Windows_last_submissions.width`.

Thank you! Hopefully I am clear.

Comment: Has Windows_last_submission one row only?

Comment: No, it is a view for Windows_submissions with LIMIT 1 clause.  It inlcudes fname,lname,email,width,height,material,type,minbid,maxbid

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT bp.*, b.company 
FROM `DBPREFIXwindows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `DBPREFIXwindows_brands` b ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls
WHERE bp.width = ls.width
AND bp.height = ls.height 
AND bp.material = ls.material
AND bp.type = ls.type
AND (bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minbid AND ls.maxbid )
```

Comment: You're the man!  hey wonder what method you would use to show if one of multiple options are present.   For example, User can choose multiple options for 'material'...so say they choose 'vinyl' and 'steel' and 'wood' - how would I query so that if any of those appear as a displayed choice??

Comment: If you have table Windows_submissions_materials (each submission has one or more materials) then you use condition bp.material in (select sm.material from Windows_submissions_materials sm where ls.id = sm.ls_id)